# Applescript Error -1700, cant make ~/Desktop/ into an alias

Tags: macos, applescript

```
set source to (choose folder default location ("~/Desktop/") with multiple selections allowed)
repeat with filetocopy in source
    set n to (quoted form of (POSIX path of filetocopy)) & " "
    set dir to do shell script "dirname " & n
    set bn to do shell script "basename " & n
    set n2 to "." & bn
    set n3 to dir & "/" & n2
    do shell script "mv " & n & space & quoted form of n3
end repeat
display dialog "Folders Hidden!" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
```

It refuses to make `~/` into an alias.  However, I can't hard-code the path with my username as I am releasing this for friends. Any simple solutions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Relative file paths with Applescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24152552/relative-file-paths-with-applescript)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778426/expand-a-posix-path-with-prefix-using-applescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the ~/. Use `(Path to desktop)` instead.

```
set source to (choose folder default location (path to desktop) with multiple selections allowed)
```