# Expand a POSIX path with prefix "~" (using AppleScript)

Tags: applescript

`StandardAdditions` has the [`path to`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW19) command  and we can use it to get known locations.

For example, `path to home folder` returns a file reference to the `user folder` and if we want the `posix path`, we can do `POSIX path of ((path to home folder) as text)`.

---

In `Terminal.app` we can use the tilde character (`~`) to represent the `home folder`.

How can we do this `tilde expanding` in `AppleScript`?

Answer (score 5):

Started with `OS X 10.10` you can easily access `Cocoa classes` and their functions and properties:

```
use framework "Foundation"

expandTilde("~/Desktop")

on expandTilde(givenPath)
    -- create a temporary Obj-C/Cocoa NSString object with the givenPath
    set tempCocoaString to current application's NSString's stringWithString:givenPath
    -- call the object's stringByExpandingTildeInPath method
    -- to create a new path with expanded tilde
    return (tempCocoaString's stringByExpandingTildeInPath) as string
end expandTilde
```

In `10.9` you have to define such handlers in `Scripting Libraries`, that's less nice than it sounds. But in `10.10` this works out of the box!

Answer (score 1):

Zero

There is more than one way to skin that cat. As you pointed out, or with the simple:

[`system attribute`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-DontLinkElementID_822) `"HOME"`

And then concatenate on the remaining path.

Comment: Cool | Note:  `system attribute` gets a list of all defined environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

*More coming soon*

---

> How to expand a `posix path` that can start with the `tilde` character `~`?
>   (*`~` represents the `home folder`*)

Here the script+demo:

```
#

demo()

# ------------------------------------------------------------
#
# expandTildeInPath ( localPath, outputStyle )
#
# ------------------------------------------------------------
# When outputStyle is true  : returns posix path
# When outputStyle is false : returns alias
# ------------------------------------------------------------
# localPath format:
# ------------------------------------------------------------
# • posix path - a posix path (can start with a  tilde "~")
# • alias
# • path (text) with ":"  => (alias as text) produces this
# ------------------------------------------------------------
on expandTildeInPath(localPath, outputStyle)

    # ------------------------------------------------------------
    # If necessary, convert localPath to text and posix path:
    # ------------------------------------------------------------

    if (class of localPath is alias) then
        # alias
        set localPath to POSIX path of (localPath as text)
    else if (class of localPath is text) and (localPath contains ":") then
        # (fileAlias as text) produces such a colon delimited path:
        set localPath to POSIX path of localPath
    end if

    set resultPath to localPath

    # -------------------------------
    # If necessary, expand tilde:
    # -------------------------------

    if localPath starts with "~" then

        # input is like: "~", "~/" or something with a sub path, like "~/Movies"
        set homeFolder to POSIX path of ((path to home folder) as text)
        if (localPath = "~") or (localPath = "~/") then
            # no sub-path
            set resultPath to homeFolder
        else
            if not (localPath starts with "~/") then
                # this is not a valid path to expand but an item that starts with "~"
                return localPath
            end if
            # add sub-path
             set subPath to ((characters 3 thru -1) of aPath) as text
             set sDel to "/"
             if (subPath starts with sDel) then set sDel to ""
             set resultPath to homeFolder & sDel & subPath
        end if
    end if

    # -------------------------------
    # return posix path or alias:
    # -------------------------------

    if outputStyle then
        return (POSIX path of resultPath)
    else
        # the location must exist or "as alias" throws an error.
        try
            set a to (resultPath as POSIX file) as alias
            return a
        on error
            log "*** Error ***" & resultPath & " does not exist"
            return localPath
        end try
    end if

end expandTildeInPath





# ------------------------------------------------------------
# Sub Routines for Demo
# ------------------------------------------------------------

on demo()

    set asAlias to false
    set asPosixPath to true

    # Does not expand since its a name that starts with "~":
    logDemo("~testFile", asAlias)

    # FolderThatDoesNotExist:
    logDemo("~/FolderThatDoesNotExist", asAlias) # this throws an error (in the log) and returns the unchanged input
    logDemo("~/FolderThatDoesNotExist", asPosixPath) # returns expanded posix path (existing or not)

    # Main Usage 
    logDemo("~", asPosixPath)
    logDemo("~", asAlias)
    logDemo("~/", asPosixPath)
    logDemo("~/", asAlias)

    logDemo("~/Documents/", asPosixPath)
    logDemo("~/Documents/", asAlias)

    # convert a posix path like "/Applications" to alias
    logDemo("/Applications", asAlias)

    set input to "~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Library.xml"

    set filePosixPath to expandTildeInPath(input, asPosixPath)
    set fileAlias to expandTildeInPath(input, asAlias)

    log quoted form of input
    log quoted form of filePosixPath
    log fileAlias
    logLine()

    # Using alias with Finder is so easy:
    tell application "Finder"
        if exists fileAlias then
            # activate
            # reveal fileAlias
        end if
    end tell


    # --------------------------
    # Other input formats:
    # --------------------------
    # This is also possible (not intended but it works):

    # we can use text paths (containing ":"):
    logDemo((path to documents folder as text), false)

    # we can use aliases:
    # (makes no sense at all when we return an alias but this is to show that it works)
    logDemo((path to documents folder), false)

    # Same as above but output as posix path:
    logDemo((path to documents folder as text), true)
    logDemo((path to documents folder), true)

end demo

on logLine()
    log "---------------------------------------------"
end logLine

on logDemo(inputPath, outputStyle)
    set a to expandTildeInPath(inputPath, outputStyle)
    if outputStyle then
        log "input: " & inputPath & " output: " & quoted form of a
    else
        log "input: " & inputPath & "      output (next line): "
        log a # don't mix with text or it does not show the "alias" in the log
    end if
    logLine()
end logDemo

# ------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

Here a little addition to show the system attributes:

```
set saList to system attribute
repeat with sa in saList
    log quoted form of sa & " = " & quoted form of (system attribute sa)
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a handy applescript one-liner that resolves any posix path beginning with a tilde (Sample path included.) Afterwards you'll find sample conversions to other path formats.

```
set psxPTH to "~/Library/Scripts/"
if character 1 of psxPTH contains "~" then set psxPTH to POSIX path of (path to home folder) & text (2 + (offset of "~" in psxPTH)) thru -1 of psxPTH
------>"/Users/Mr.Science/Library/Scripts/"
```

--other steps after the posix is resolved...

```
set hfsPTH to (POSIX file psxPTH) as text
------> "Macintosh_Harddrive:Users:Mr.Science:Library:Scripts:"

set alsPTH to alias hfsPTH
------> alias "Macintosh_Harddrive:Users:Mr.Science:Library:Scripts:"

tell application "Finder" to set vrbspth to item alsPTH
------> folder "Scripts" of folder "Library" of folder "Mr.Science" of folder "Users" of startup disk of application "Finder"
```