# Applescript: How to open a file with file path stored in clipboard

Tags: applescript

I have read these two posts [Copy pure text from clipboard using AppleScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190868/copy-pure-text-from-clipboard-using-applescript) and [Applescript: How to open a file with the default program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126661/applescript-how-to-open-a-file-with-the-default-program).

The following code works. I can open file "file.pdf".

```
tell application "Finder"
    open POSIX file "/Users/myName/file.pdf"
end tell
```

And so I come up with the following code.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set filePath to (the clipboard as text)
    open POSIX file filePath
end tell
```

But surprisingly it does not work. It returns an error (Finder got an error: Can’t get POSIX file "/Users/myName/file.pdf")

Comment: `POSIX file` can be a bit quirky in a Finder tell statement, a coercion usually works better, for example `open filePath as POSIX file`

Comment: The Finder is actually not needed: `open location POSIX file (get the clipboard) as alias`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As red_menace said, `open filePath as POSIX file` works.
The following code works.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set filePath to (the clipboard as text)
    open filePath as POSIX file
end tell
```